# How to fix Anaconda ProxyError in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda, ubuntu-20.04

I have instilled a Anaconda with the infromation:

```
:~$ conda info
conda info --all

     active environment : None
       user config file : /home/qic220/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/qic220/.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.3
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.8.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.1
                          __glibc=2.31
       base environment : /home/qic220/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/noarch
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/noarch
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/qic220/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/qic220/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/qic220/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/qic220/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.3 Linux/5.4.0-42-generic ubuntu/20.04.1 glibc/2.31
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/qic220/anaconda3

sys.version: 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 16:21:59) 
...
sys.prefix: /home/qic220/anaconda3
sys.executable: /home/qic220/anaconda3/bin/python
conda location: /home/qic220/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda
conda-build: /home/qic220/anaconda3/bin/conda-build
conda-convert: /home/qic220/anaconda3/bin/conda-convert
conda-debug: /home/qic220/anaconda3/bin/conda-debug
conda-develop: /home/qic220/anaconda3/bin/conda-develop
conda-env: /home/qic220/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
conda-index: /home/qic220/anaconda3/bin/conda-index
conda-inspect: /home/qic220/anaconda3/bin/conda-inspect
conda-metapackage: /home/qic220/anaconda3/bin/conda-metapackage
conda-render: /home/qic220/anaconda3/bin/conda-render
conda-server: /home/qic220/anaconda3/bin/conda-server
conda-skeleton: /home/qic220/anaconda3/bin/conda-skeleton
conda-verify: /home/qic220/anaconda3/bin/conda-verify
user site dirs: 

ALL_PROXY: <set>
CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_ROOT: /home/qic220/anaconda3
C_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/local/cuda/include:
DEFAULTS_PATH: /usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
HTTPS_PROXY: <set>
HTTP_PROXY: <set>
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/ovito-basic-3.3.1-x86_64/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64::/opt/vmd-1.9.4a48/lib
MANDATORY_PATH: /usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
NO_PROXY: <set>
PATH: /home/qic220/anaconda3/bin:/opt/ovito-basic-3.3.1-x86_64/bin:/home/qic220/lammps-stable_29Oct2020/src:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/software/anaconda3/bin:/opt/vmd-1.9.4a48/bin
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
SSL_CERT_FILE: <not set>
WINDOWPATH: 2
```

But when I tried to install a package, it failed and a **ProxyError arised**:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge hoomd
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

ProxyError: Conda cannot proceed due to an error in your proxy configuration.
Check for typos and other configuration errors in any '.netrc' file in your home directory,
any environment variables ending in '_PROXY', and any other system-wide proxy
configuration settings.
```

Actually, even I just use `conda update conda`, there still is ProxyError.

I have check `env | grep proxy`, nothing shown on my screen.

And I also modified .condsrc as:

```
proxy_servers:
    http: http://username:password@corp.com:8080
    https: https://username:password@corp.com:8080
channels:
  - defaults
show_channel_urls: true
default_channels:
  - http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main
  - http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free
  - http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/r
custom_channels:
  conda-forge: http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
  msys2: http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
  bioconda: http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
  menpo: http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
  pytorch: http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
  simpleitk: http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
```

After `source ~/.condarc`, it still not work. Is anyone have idea to fixed my problem?

Comment: Have you confirmed with your IT department that your settings for the proxy are correct, i.e that you ahve correctly replaced `username:password@corp.com:8080` with the settings needed for your network?